# Stable homeomorphism theorem and the annulus theorem

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, homeomorphism

Brown and Gluck [BG] proved in 1964 that the stable homeomorphism conjecture implies the annulus conjecture.

- Is the proof of this implication difficult?
- Is there any other place with the proof of this implication?

My collaborators and I are working on a problem that requires both the stable homeomorphism theorem (SHT) and the annulus theorem (AT), so I would like to understand how hard it is to conclude AT from SHT.

[BG] *Brown, Morton; Gluck, Herman*, [**Stable structures on manifolds. I: Homeomorphis of $\mathbb{S}^ n$.**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970481), Ann. Math. (2) 79, 1-17, (1964). [ZBL0122.17903](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0122.17903).

Comment: You could just read the proof in the cited paper (it takes about six pages with preliminaries given by a ten-page paper of Brown on locally flat embeddings)? Whether it is hard depends on your background. I am not aware of another dire proof of this implication, but you could follow Kirby-Siebenmann in doing SHT => surgery theory for topological manifolds and then deduce the annulus theorem from that.

Comment: @skupers We are in the process of reading the paper by Brown and Gluck and it seems that most of the arguments in are elementary and well written. The only non-elementary argument is the generalized Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: The generalized Schoenflies theorem is also fairly elementary.  I have an expository note on it here that is basically entirely self-contained: https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/Schoenflies.pdf

Comment: @AndyPutman I know your notes very well. You shold publish them somewhere. Expositiones Math?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: You're not the first person to suggest that I publish them.  At some point I'll definitely do something with them (possibly collect some into a book).

Comment: @AndyPutman It is a very good idea. There are plenty of well known results and of very general interest, that are not difficult to prove, but the only available sources are difficult for those who are not deeply involved into the subject. The generalized Schoenflies theorem is an example. You could also lok at the papers of Goering and Gong:  MR0215987 and MR2861086, where a nice geometric construction is presented for the Schoenflies theorem.